# Running Streamlit and FastAPI locally with an .exe - without Docker

Tags: python, makefile, web-applications, fastapi, streamlit

I am trying to run both Streamlit and FastAPI on localhost at the same time. I know it's possible with Docker, but due to company restrictions we can't use Docker.

I've tried to create an executable with Pyinstaller, but it's not as reliable as I thought it would be. Even a simple example took ages to configure due to multiple bugs (mostly Streamlit-related). As such, is there any other solution that would create an executable file that would run these two services at the same time? Perhaps a MAKEFILE?

Thank you!

Comment: Why not use shell script?